# Poco Cipher leak

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind, poco

I'm going crazy and after I have googled without answer I'm going to try to write here. 
I have Ubuntu 16.04, GCC 5.4.0, Poco 1.7.8-all and OpenSSL 1.1.0e.

and these few lines of code:

```
int main()
{
    const std::string AES_NAME = "aes-128-cbc";
    Cipher::Ptr uptrCipher = CipherFactory::defaultFactory().createCipher(CipherKey(AES_NAME, "abcdef", "123456"));
    std::string plainText = "This is my secret information";
    std::string encrypted = uptrCipher->encryptString(plainText, Cipher::ENC_BASE64);
    return 0;
}
```

If I run Valgrind I got this error (my apologize for the lengh):

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./CipherTest 
==32223== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==32223== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==32223== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==32223== Command: ./CipherTest
==32223== 
==32223== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==32223==    at 0x4C2F24B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32223==    by 0x5A3F369: __cxa_finalize (cxa_finalize.c:56)
==32223==    by 0x687CAB2: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libPocoFoundationd.so.48)
==32223==    by 0x4010C16: _dl_fini (dl-fini.c:235)
==32223==    by 0x5A3EFF7: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)
==32223==    by 0x5A3F044: exit (exit.c:104)
==32223==    by 0x5A25836: (below main) (libc-start.c:325)
==32223==  Address 0x737a9d0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 20 free'd
==32223==    at 0x4C2F24B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32223==    by 0x5A3F369: __cxa_finalize (cxa_finalize.c:56)
==32223==    by 0x4ED7542: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.48)
==32223==    by 0x4010C16: _dl_fini (dl-fini.c:235)
==32223==    by 0x5A3EFF7: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)
==32223==    by 0x5A3F044: exit (exit.c:104)
==32223==    by 0x5A25836: (below main) (libc-start.c:325)
==32223==  Block was alloc'd at
==32223==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32223==    by 0x4F69C0C: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.48)
==32223==    by 0x4ED7212: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.48)
==32223==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==32223==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==32223== 
==32223== 
==32223== HEAP SUMMARY:
==32223==     in use at exit: 73,124 bytes in 13 blocks
==32223==   total heap usage: 3,914 allocs, 3,912 frees, 256,412 bytes allocated
==32223== 
==32223== 18 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 13
==32223==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32223==    by 0x558EAEC: void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x558EC4B: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x688F40D: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (DateTimeFormat.cpp:31)
==32223==    by 0x688FB4D: _GLOBAL__sub_I_DateTimeFormat.cpp (DateTimeFormat.cpp:63)
==32223==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==32223==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==32223== 
==32223== 20 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 13
==32223==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32223==    by 0x558EAEC: void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x558EC4B: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x688F165: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (DateTimeFormat.cpp:23)
==32223==    by 0x688FB4D: _GLOBAL__sub_I_DateTimeFormat.cpp (DateTimeFormat.cpp:63)
==32223==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==32223==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==32223== 
==32223== 20 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 13
==32223==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32223==    by 0x558EAEC: void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x558EC4B: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x688F1BA: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (DateTimeFormat.cpp:24)
==32223==    by 0x688FB4D: _GLOBAL__sub_I_DateTimeFormat.cpp (DateTimeFormat.cpp:63)
==32223==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==32223==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==32223== 
==32223== 20 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 13
==32223==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32223==    by 0x558EAEC: void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x558EC4B: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x6942982: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (URI.cpp:32)
==32223==    by 0x6942A63: _GLOBAL__sub_I_URI.cpp (URI.cpp:915)
==32223==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==32223==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==32223== 
==32223== 21 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 13
==32223==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32223==    by 0x558EAEC: void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x558EC4B: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x688F3B8: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (DateTimeFormat.cpp:30)
==32223==    by 0x688FB4D: _GLOBAL__sub_I_DateTimeFormat.cpp (DateTimeFormat.cpp:63)
==32223==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==32223==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==32223== 
==32223== 25 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 13
==32223==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32223==    by 0x558EAEC: void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x558EC4B: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x688F20F: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (DateTimeFormat.cpp:25)
==32223==    by 0x688FB4D: _GLOBAL__sub_I_DateTimeFormat.cpp (DateTimeFormat.cpp:63)
==32223==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==32223==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==32223== 
==32223== 25 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 13
==32223==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32223==    by 0x558EAEC: void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x558EC4B: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x688F264: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (DateTimeFormat.cpp:26)
==32223==    by 0x688FB4D: _GLOBAL__sub_I_DateTimeFormat.cpp (DateTimeFormat.cpp:63)
==32223==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==32223==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==32223== 
==32223== 25 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 8 of 13
==32223==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32223==    by 0x558EAEC: void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x558EC4B: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x688F2B9: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (DateTimeFormat.cpp:27)
==32223==    by 0x688FB4D: _GLOBAL__sub_I_DateTimeFormat.cpp (DateTimeFormat.cpp:63)
==32223==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==32223==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==32223== 
==32223== 25 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 9 of 13
==32223==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32223==    by 0x558EAEC: void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x558EC4B: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x688F30E: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (DateTimeFormat.cpp:28)
==32223==    by 0x688FB4D: _GLOBAL__sub_I_DateTimeFormat.cpp (DateTimeFormat.cpp:63)
==32223==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==32223==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==32223== 
==32223== 25 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 10 of 13
==32223==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32223==    by 0x558EAEC: void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x558EC4B: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x688F363: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (DateTimeFormat.cpp:29)
==32223==    by 0x688FB4D: _GLOBAL__sub_I_DateTimeFormat.cpp (DateTimeFormat.cpp:63)
==32223==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==32223==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==32223== 
==32223== 28 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 11 of 13
==32223==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32223==    by 0x558EAEC: void std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x558EC4B: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==32223==    by 0x6918141: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (RotateStrategy.cpp:47)
==32223==    by 0x69181B7: _GLOBAL__sub_I_RotateStrategy.cpp (RotateStrategy.cpp:115)
==32223==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==32223==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==32223==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==32223== 
==32223== 168 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 12 of 13
==32223==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32223==    by 0x7038D9D: CRYPTO_zalloc (in /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==32223==    by 0x5253907: Poco::Crypto::(anonymous namespace)::CryptoTransformImpl::CryptoTransformImpl(evp_cipher_st const*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > const&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > const&, Poco::Crypto::(anonymous namespace)::CryptoTransformImpl::Direction) (CipherImpl.cpp:100)
==32223==    by 0x5253E6F: Poco::Crypto::CipherImpl::createEncryptor() (CipherImpl.cpp:218)
==32223==    by 0x5252ACA: Poco::Crypto::Cipher::encrypt(std::istream&, std::ostream&, Poco::Crypto::Cipher::Encoding) (Cipher.cpp:67)
==32223==    by 0x52528BB: Poco::Crypto::Cipher::encryptString(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Crypto::Cipher::Encoding) (Cipher.cpp:49)
==32223==    by 0x4010FA: main (main.cpp:37)
==32223== 
==32223== LEAK SUMMARY:
==32223==    definitely lost: 420 bytes in 12 blocks
==32223==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32223==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32223==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==32223==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32223== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==32223== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==32223== 
==32223== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==32223== ERROR SUMMARY: 23 errors from 13 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Following the last statements from the bottom, I went in the Cipher.cpp and CipherImp.cpp at the line #100 I found out:

```
#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER >= 0x10100000L
        _pContext = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
```

It seems is not deleted...I have no idea. But I'm sure that I'm making some mistakes.

Did anybody meet this error?
Where I wrong in the code?

Thank you

Cristano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer.

It seems that with OpenSSL 1.1.0 the method to free resources is EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx).

I have included the CipherImpl in my project and changed the line below in the distructor:

```
CryptoTransformImpl::~CryptoTransformImpl()
    {
#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER >= 0x10100000L
        //IT WAS: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(_pContext);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(_pContext);

#else
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&_context);
#endif
    }
```

I ran again Valgrind:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./CipherTest 
==32869== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==32869== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==32869== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==32869== Command: ./CipherTest
==32869== 
Sono nel costruttore con Openssl v.269484127
==32869== 
==32869== HEAP SUMMARY:
==32869==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==32869==   total heap usage: 3,893 allocs, 3,892 frees, 253,681 bytes allocated
==32869== 
==32869== LEAK SUMMARY:
==32869==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32869==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32869==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32869==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==32869==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32869== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==32869== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==32869== 
==32869== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==32869== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```